# Are questions about translations of database terminology into other languages tolerated here?

Tags: discussion

On [http://german.stackexchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/what-is-the-german-word-for-a-sql-lookup-table) we have the question for the German translation of "lookup table".

I'm very unsure we should allow such questions to some extend. But I think only on this site is a good chance to address the people who know the answer.

Most German developers don't care about German translations. Only those teaching SQL and Databases are eager to use only German words. I see a little chance to reach one of them here and to learn if they established a translation for this termini.

I could imagine to maintain some CWs here containing translations of standard terminology from English to some other languages.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be okay with it, but instead of asking a question for each term to be translated, I think in the long run it might make more sense to have a single 'question' with translations, as we've done on cooking, rather than lots of individual questions:

- [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz)
- [False friends in international cooking terms](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16076/false-friends-in-international-cooking-terms)
- [English names of kitchenware tools](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4076/english-names-of-kitchenware-tools)

(not that cooking doesn't have the individual questions, asking about [cuts of meat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13138/what-is-the-correct-french-word-for-brisket), differentiation of [corn meal](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/what-is-the-difference-between-grits-and-polenta), [etc](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language))

Answer (score 1):

I can understand where the German (or another language) is used to introduce and explain a concept but then the English words are used from then on. This is what will be used day to day. I hear this every day (English jargon interspersed in German before, now Maltese)

But anyone here has to have some command of English anyway. By that time, it is too late.

I would suggest that the academics should prepare their students for the real world: they would be best placed to deal with their own native languages. Not us.

Off topic: are you familiar with [InsideSQL.org](http://www.insidesql.org/), a German language SQL Server web site?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the German language and usage stackexchange?

I think that is the place to ask such questions, possibly. Often "how does this translate" are asked on the English variant, I think.

Comment: Thanks. But that is the site where the question comes from http://german.stackexchange = German language and usage.

Comment: oh, haha, it just clicked with me how wrong I was ... /facepalm ~~ I completely missed the first line of the post ... gaah